# Recurrence Relation on Finance

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a) Find a recurrence relation for the amount of money in a savings account after $n$ months $a_n$, if the interest rate is $.5\%$ interest per month and initially the account has \$$1000$. 
Solve the recurrence by finding a formula for $a_n$.

b) Repeat a) assuming that $100$ additional dollars are deposited into the account at the end of each month. Find a recurrence relation for the amount of money in the account at the end of month $n$, $b_n$ and solve the recurrence by finding a  formula for $b_n$.

I know this is that we have to find the recurrence relation between the amounts of the money. I never dealt these kind of problems before.

Answer (score 0):

If I have $a_0=1000$ Dollars and my bank gives me $r=.5\%$ per month, then I have $a_1=(1+r)a_0$ next month, $a_2=(1+r)a_1=(1+r)^2a_0$ Dollars the month after, etc.

If I deposit $100$ Dollars extra, I have $b_1=(1+r)b_0+100$, $b_2=(1+r)b_1+100=(1+r)^2b_0+(1+r)100+100$, etc. ...